# Time in Hrs or Hrs and Minutes SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate productivity.

```
Productivity = some count/ no of Hrs
```

I have time in `HH:MM`

For example if I take time `1 hrs 30 minutes`

Productivity will be

```
Productivity = some count / 1.3?
```

OR

```
Productivity = some count / 1.5?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 1 hour and 30 minutes, that is 1.5 hours.  You would want to take your calculation as: `yourValue / 1.5` to get Productivity in `units / Hour`

You would likely want something like:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, @yourTime) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, @yourTime) / 60.) AS pHours;
```

or more fully something like this, where `@Time` is how long the task took:

```
SELECT @workAccomplished /
   (DATEPART(HOUR, @Time) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, @Time) / 60.)) AS Productivity;
```

If you were dividing by 1.3, you would be calculating 1 Hour and 18 minutes, as 0.3 hours = 18 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        declare @workaccomplished int = 240
        declare @timeworked int = (SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2007-05-07 09:53:01', '2007-05-08 09:53:01'))

        --datediff parameters: hour, startingtime , endtime
        declare @productivity numeric(8,4) = @workaccomplished / @timeworked

        select @productivity
```

Comment: Your current approach will not work. `Datediff(hour, )` will round, you will not get the minutes turned into fractional hours. This will make your calculation off.

Comment: @Adam Wenger You're right sorry. Forgot to add the minutes bit :\